# jQuery UI Sortable, how to determine current location and new location in update event?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have:

```
<ul id="sortableList">
     <li>item 1</li>
     <li>item 2</li>
     <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I have wired into the `update: function(event, ui) { }` but am not sure how to get the original and new position of the element.  If i move item 3 to be above item 1, I want the original position to be **2** (0 based index) and the new position of item 3 to be **0**.

Comment: The last answer from Richard with least number of upvotes is the best and cleanest solution, especially when you are using AngularJS or any other MVC frameworks where you dont want to read a custom attribute inside your controller!

Answer (score 101, accepted):

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
    start: function(e, ui) {
        // creates a temporary attribute on the element with the old index
        $(this).attr('data-previndex', ui.item.index());
    },
    update: function(e, ui) {
        // gets the new and old index then removes the temporary attribute
        var newIndex = ui.item.index();
        var oldIndex = $(this).attr('data-previndex');
        $(this).removeAttr('data-previndex');
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use `ui.item.data('previndex')` also

Answer (score 18):

When the update function is invoked the ui.item.sortable has not been updated, however the UI element has visually moved.
This allows you in the update function to get old position and new position.

```
   $('#sortable').sortable({    
        update: function(e, ui) {
            // ui.item.sortable is the model but it is not updated until after update
            var oldIndex = ui.item.sortable.index;

            // new Index because the ui.item is the node and the visual element has been reordered
            var newIndex = ui.item.index();
        }    
});
```

Comment: This is the best answer and the cleanest solution! Thanks Richard!

Comment: Doesn't work on jQuery 1.7, jQuery UI 1.8 - although this solution sounds very promising

Comment: To be specific: ui.item.sortable.index doesn't exist; and ui.item.sortable().index() returns allready updated index.

Comment: For me `ui.item.sortable.index` & `ui.item.index()` both were returning same integer. I started using `ui.item.sortable.dropindex` to obtain the new index

Answer (score 10):

You have several possibilities to check the old and the new position. I would put them into arrays.

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
    start: function(e, ui) {
        // puts the old positions into array before sorting
        var old_position = $(this).sortable('toArray');
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
        // grabs the new positions now that we've finished sorting
        var new_position = $(this).sortable('toArray');
    }
});
```

And you can then easily extract what you need.

Comment: list items must have IDs. otherwise it generates empty array

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for an answer to the same issue. based on what Frankie contributed, I was able to get both the start and end "orders".  I had an issue with variable scope using the var, so I just stored them as .data() instead of local vars:

```
$(this).data("old_position",$(this).sortable("toArray"))
```

and

```
$(this).data("new_position",$(this).sortable("toArray"))
```

now you can call it up like this (from the update/end functions):

```
console.log($(this).data("old_position"))
console.log($(this).data("new_position"))
```

Credit still goes to Frankie :)

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
start: function(e, ui) {
    // puts the old positions into array before sorting
    var old_position = ui.item.index();
},
update: function(event, ui) {
    // grabs the new positions now that we've finished sorting
    var new_position = ui.item.index();
}
});
```

Comment: This worked for me! It's worth noting that if you need to reference old_position within update() just declare it before the sortable.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me,

```
$('#app').sortable({
    handle: '.handle',

    start: function(evt, ui){
        $(ui.item).data('old-ndex' , ui.item.index());
    },

    update: function(evt, ui) {
        var old_index = $(ui.item).data('old-ndex');
        var new_index = ui.item.index();

        alert('old_index -'+old_index+' new index -'+new_index);

    }
});
```