# jQueryUI Sortable start position / end position in combination with AngularJS?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angular-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

According to this question (and answers), I should be able to get the original start position and end position in several ways:

[jQuery UI Sortable, how to determine current location and new location in update event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601827/jquery-ui-sortable-how-to-determine-current-location-and-new-location-in-update)

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
    start: function(e, ui) {
        // creates a temporary attribute on the element with the old index
        $(this).attr('data-previndex', ui.item.index());
    },
    update: function(e, ui) {
        // gets the new and old index then removes the temporary attribute
        var newIndex = ui.item.index();
        var oldIndex = $(this).attr('data-previndex');
        $(this).removeAttr('data-previndex');
    }
});
```

OR all within the update event (preferable):

```
$('#sortable').sortable({    
        update: function(e, ui) {
            // ui.item.sortable is the model but it is not updated until after update
            var oldIndex = ui.item.sortable.index;

            // new Index because the ui.item is the node and the visual element has been reordered
            var newIndex = ui.item.index();
        }    
});
```

However, as also mentioned in some comments on the question, this isn't working for me. I should perhaps mention that I'm using sortable in combination with AngularJS, specifically [the wrapper provided by AngularUI](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/blob/master/src/sortable.js). For the first example, I replaced `$(this)` with `$(e.target)`.

Any clues as to why this isn't working, and how to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I've found the solution:

```
$('#sortable').sortable({ 
    update: function(e, ui) {
        oldPos = ui.item.sortable.index;
        newPos = ui.item.sortable.dropindex;
    }
});
```

This is based on the [extra properties](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/blob/master/API.md#uiitemsortable-api-documentation) that the AngularUI wrapper for Sortable provides.