# Sortable - Update Existing Array - jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an existing array of elements, example:

`arr=[{name:1,data:xyz},{name:2,data:abc},{name:3, data:lmn}; {name:4,data:opq}]`

This items are populated according to their name on UI.
Example: `1 2 3 4 5`

I have implemented Sortable of jQuery. Instead of creating a new array, I wish to update the exiting array `arr` according to the new position of the elements after the user has done performing the drag & drop operation on the above elements.

User can move elements present inside the array `arr` and cannot introduce any dragged object from outside the `1 2 3 4 5` elements' list, example: 2 can be moved to 5 or 1 can be moved to 3 etc etc.

Elements HTML:

```
<ul class= "tree-list">
 <li class="li_class"><span class="span_class"> 1 </span></li>
 <li class="li_class"><span class="span_class"> 2 </span></li>
 <li class="li_class"><span class="span_class"> 3 </span></li>
 <li class="li_class"><span class="span_class"> 4 </span></li>
 <li class="li_class"><span class="span_class"> 5 </span></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(function() {
            var data = $(".tree-list").sortable({
              delay: 150,
              axis: "y",
      
            update: function(event, ui) {
                var index = ui.item.index();
                console.log("Moved to new position: " + index);
                var children = $('ul.tree-list').children()
                // What to do here
           
            })
     
            $( ".tree-list" ).disableSelection();
        });
```

Array created dynamically:

```
someFunc(data){
    let htmlString= " <ul class =\"tree-list\" "
    for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        if(typeof(item) === "string"){
          htmlString += "<li class=\" li_class \"" + item + "\">";
                                     }
        else if(typeof(item) === "object"){
          htmlString += "<li>";
          htmlString += "span class=\"span_class\""  
                                     }
           htmlString += "</li>"
                                   }
       }
htmlString += "</ul>";
return (htmlString);

}
```

Comment: Are the `li` and `span` elements created from the array? If so you can simplify the logic by adding the objects to the element's metadata and simply using `map()` to re-build the array in the correct order when each sort operation happens.

Comment: yes, they're created dynamically. Updated the code, could you please take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to recreate your example using initial array :

what I've done is , at first create `data-previndex` to store previous index on li position update using start srotable  : ( credits to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8441383/2932476) )

then every update, call the `array_move` (credits to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5306832/2932476) ) which update element on the js array , depending on the previous and current index

See below working snippet :

```js
$(function() {
  let arr = [{name:1,data:"xyz"}, {name:2,data:"abc"}, {name:3, data:"lmn"}, {name:4,data:"opq"}, {name:5,data:"stu"}]
  
  let $treeList = $(".tree-list");
  
  arr.forEach(element => {
    let liNode = `<li class="li_class"><span class="span_class"> ${element.name} </span></li>`
    $treeList.append(liNode);
  })
   
  var data = $(".tree-list").sortable({
    delay: 150,
    axis: "y",
    start: function(e, ui) {
        // creates a temporary attribute on the element with the old index
        // credits to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601827/jquery-ui-sortable-how-to-determine-current-location-and-new-location-in-update
        $(this).attr('data-previndex', ui.item.index());
    },

    update: function(event, ui) {
      var newIndex = ui.item.index();
      var oldIndex = $(this).attr('data-previndex');
      
      
      var children = $('ul.tree-list').children()
      // What to do here
      arr = array_move(arr, oldIndex, newIndex);
      console.clear()
      console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
    }
  });

  $(".tree-list").disableSelection();
});

function array_move(arr, old_index, new_index) {
    if (new_index >= arr.length) {
        var k = new_index - arr.length + 1;
        while (k--) {
            arr.push(undefined);
        }
    }
    arr.splice(new_index, 0, arr.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
    return arr; 
};
```

```css
@import url("https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tree-list">
</ul>
```